Error al hacer consulta con PHP
estoy intentando hacer una consulta en PHP y que me devuelva una tabla con los resultados que contengan las los caracteres que he escrito y me devuelve este error:
POST https://brandon-engineer.com/sistein/search_data.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
El script es el siguiente:
.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
    const search = document.querySelector('#search')
    const tableContainer = document.querySelector('#results tbody')
    const resultContainer = document.querySelector('#resultsContainer')
    const errorContainer = document.querySelector('.error-container')
    let search_criteria = '';
        if(search){
            search.addEventListener('input', event =>{
                search_criteria = event.target.value.toUpperCase()
                showResults()
            })
        }
        const searchData = async() => {
            let searchData = new FormData()
            searchData.append('search_criteria', search_criteria)
            try{
                const response = await fetch('search_data.php',{
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: searchData
                })
                return response.json()
            }catch(error){
                alert(`${'Hubo un error y no podemos procesar la solicitud en este momento. Razones: '}${error.message}`)
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
        //funcion para mostrar los datos
        const showResults =() =>{
            searchData()
            .then(dataResults =>{
                console.log(dataResults)
                tableContainer.innerHTML = ''
                if(typeof dataResults.data !== 'undefined' && !dataResults.data){
                    errorContainer.style.display = 'block'
                    errorContainer.querySelector('p').innerHTML = `
                    No hay resultados: <span class="bold">${search_criteria}</span>`
                    resultContainer.style.display = 'none'
                }else{
                    resultContainer.style.display = 'block'
                    errorContainer.style.display = 'none'
                    for (const author of dataResults){
                        const row = document.createElement('tr')
                        row.innerHTML = `
                        <td>${author.id}</td>
                        <td>${author.desc.toUpperCase().replace(search_criteria, '<span class="bold">$&</span>')}</td>
                        `
                        tableContainer.appendChild(row)
                    }

                }
            })
        }
})

Estoy intentando acceder a una base de datos de mariaDB alojado en un VPS y los datos que he puesto para el acceso a la base de datos son:
<?php

$server = "IP del servidor";
$username = "testsistein";
$password = "******";
$database = "sistein";

//crear conexion

$db = new mysqli($server,$username,$password,$database);

if ($db ->connect_error){

    die("Error al conectar con la base de datos: " . $db->connect_error);

}

Todos los archivos los tengo en la raiz de la carpeta es decir, tanto index.html, database.php, style.css, script.js como search_data.php estan en la misma carpeta a la que estoy haciendo la prueba.
Actualmente tengo los archivos en la siguiente ruta de mi vps:
https://brandon-engineer.com/sistein/
El codigo de search data es:
<?php

require_once('database.php');

$search_criteria = $_POST['search_criteria'];

//consulta

$query = "SELECT id,descripcion FROM obras
WHERE descripcion LIKE '%".$search_criteria."%';

$authors = [];
$errors = ['data' => false];


$getAuthors = $db->query($query);

if($getAuthors->num_rows > 0){
    while($data = $getAuthors->fetch_assoc()){

        $authors[] = $data;

    }
    echo json_encode($authors);
}else{
    echo json_encode($errors);
}


Hola. Revisa el log de errores en tu servidor. Otra cosa, si la contraseña que hay en la pregunta es real debes cambiarla de inmediato pues te acabas de exponer al ataque de hackers al publicarla en Internet. Nunca pongas credenciales reales en las preguntas.

Es un usuario que solo tiene acceso a esa base de datos test y no hace nada asique en un principio no me preocupa, aun así lo he cambiado

me sale este error:
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "]", expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number in /var/www/vhosts/brandon-engineer.com/httpdocs/sistein/search_data.php on line 21, referer: https://brandon-engineer.com/sistein/

¿Y qué hay en la línea 21 del archivo search_data.php?

$authors[] = $data;

Esto $authors[] = $data; no es erróneo en sí mismo. El error debe ocurrir por algo más que hay en ese contexto. Convendría que agregues a la pregunta la parte del código que hay en torno a esa línea 21 pulsando en [edit]. Otra cosa, comprueba que el archivo que estás revisando está exactamente en esta ruta /var/www/vhosts/brandon-engineer.com/httpdocs/sistein/search_data.php no sea que estés mirando en otro archivo que se llame igual, pero que esté en otra ruta. Lo digo porque es extraño que esa línea dé error.

@A.Cedano He agregado el código de search_data al post

esto esta mal: $query = "SELECT id,descripcion FROM obras WHERE descripcion LIKE '%".$search_criteria."%';

debe terminar asi: ."%';";

el no cerrar las comillas dobles cuando concatenas probocan ese error tipografico

otra cosa deberias habilitar los errores en el entorno de desarrollo de lo contrario no veras los warning tampoco ... y solo cuando hago se rompa completamente sera visible en los logs...

Correcto, ya me salen en los registros que se hace el post correctamente ahora me salta error en la funcion showResults. ¿Cómo hago para habilitar los errores en el entorno de desarrollo? yo normalmente los veo en la consola del inspeccionador de codigo y no sabia que habia que configurar algo más. Muchas gracias de antemano

depden del IDE tendra caracteristicas para ver errores en tiempo real etc ... pero por lo generar hay que ir al php.ini del servidor apache en la parte donde se condigura el modulo php y agregar: error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On

En PHP tú puedes colocar variables dentro de cadenas rodeadas por comillas dobles sin ningún problema. Eso ayuda a escribir un código más claro y menos propenso a errores. Siguiendo ese criterio, puedes escribir tu consulta de este modo: $query = "SELECT id,descripcion FROM obras WHERE descripcion LIKE '%$search_criteria%'"; Aunque esto sigue estando mal, ahora desde el punto de vista de la seguridad, pues deberías usar consultas preparadas o te expones a un gravísimo peligro de inyección SQL.

o al inicio de cada archivo php dentro de las etiquetas: ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

En cuanto a los errores, si la web ya está en producción (es accesible al público), no te aconsejo que muestres los errores en pantalla. Simplemente, revisa tu log de errores para ir depurando el código. Si muestras los errores en pantalla, todos los usuarios verán esos errores, lo cual es desagradable. Y hay otro problema más grave: los mensajes de error revelan a veces información muy jugosa para usuarios mal intencionados, como rutas donde se encuentran tus archivos, nombre de la base de datos o de las tablas, etc.

Al final el tema de seguridad me da igual, como podéis ver es una web personal que la uso para experimentar y aprender cosas nuevas. Este software no esta pensado para el público(en cuanto lo desarrolle lo quitare del servidor). Aunque aprecio vuestros comentarios y los tendré en cuenta porque quiero seguir aprendiendo y mejorar cada día mas.

Entonces si quieres aprender a depurar codigo si o si necesitas ver lo errores y los warning por algun medio ... asi como y tambien puedes usar otras herramientas como xdebug ... etc...
